# Scanning/querying specific entries in a dynamodb table with lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify

I am working with AWS and using a API to trigger a lambda and the lambda contains CRUD code for the dynamodb. For example, this piece of code (in the lambda function) scans and returns all the objects:

```
app.get(path, function (req, res) {
  var params = {
    TableName: tableName,
    Select: 'ALL_ATTRIBUTES',
  };

  dynamodb.scan(params, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      res.json({ error: 'Could not load items: ' + err.message });
    }

    res.json({
      data: data.Items.map(item => {
        return item;
      }),
    });
  });
});
```

This works nicely and i've been testing this with postman.
I now want to query all items matching a specific ID from a table that is **not** the partition key. So for example: Imagine I have a database containing books. The PK is bookname. There is also an attribute that is bookyear. Multiple books can have bookyear 1997. And now I want to edit my query/scan so that it finds and returns me all books with bookyear 1997.
What would be the best way to go about this?
Thanks in advance.

Edit nr 100:
I am now using this code:

Which is cool, because the query works now! The json.tringify(data) gives me the 2 database items I wanted, which is awesome!
I am now trying to return this back to my test situation in postman. But unfortunately I get a " "message": "Internal server error"
So I don't think returning data.Items is quite right.

Comment: Your code appears to be attempting to JSONify the items even if the scan call returned an error. Move that to an else path. Also, add console.log(err) to the `if (err)` path.

Comment: Returning a value (such as `return data.Items`) from within a callback function does not have any effect on the return value from the originally called function (`dynamodb.query` in your case). This is standard async JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks. I used this:
 res.json({
            data: data.Items.map(item => {
              return item;
            }),
          });
        });

Im not sure what it does exactly yet but it works, I will look into it now!

I am still a student trying to figure this out so I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

Your call to `dynamodb.scan` is failing because you have passed it invalid parameters. Specifically, it does not support `KeyConditionExpression`. That's valid in `query` but not `scan`. You probably meant to use `FilterExpression`.

You don't see this because your error handling code doesn't surface the error correctly.

As to your question of how to return all books with bookyear 1997 ... you can add a Global Secondary Index on bookyear, then issue a query using that GSI. This is more performant than a full scan with filter.

Comment: Thanks for you help! I decided to go with querying a GSI as you can see in my edited post. Which now works nicely. It took me a while to figure out logging is also visible and cloudwatch so I just debugged from there. Now to figure out what to exactly return..